# How do I deploy file share within storage account using ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

I can successfully create a storage account using an ARM template and I realize the ARM template does not directly support creating a file share on the storage account via any of the existing providers.  I thought I would write a PowerShell script and use the custom script extension in the arm template but it seems like that can only run on a VM (typically used for post setup stuff on VM).

Is there a way to create the file share and child directory structure in PowerShell and have this executed after my ARM template is deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following powershell:

Create share

```
$storageAcct = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name yyy
New-AzStorageShare `
   -Name myshare `
   -Context $storageAcct.Context
```

Create folder.

```
New-AzStorageDirectory `
   -Context $storageAcct.Context `
   -ShareName "myshare" `
   -Path "myDirectory"
```

Upload file.

```
# this expression will put the current date and time into a new file on your scratch drive
Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\CloudDrive\SampleUpload.txt" -Force

# this expression will upload that newly created file to your Azure file share
Set-AzStorageFileContent `
   -Context $storageAcct.Context `
   -ShareName "myshare" `
   -Source "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\CloudDrive\SampleUpload.txt" `
   -Path "myDirectory\SampleUpload.txt"
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-powershell

Answer (score 2):

Old question I know, but it is now possible to create file shares using ARM templates - something like this in ARM:

```json
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('fileShareName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    }
```

Or much simpler in bicep:

```
resource myStorage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares@2019-06-01' = {
  name: '${storageAccount.name}/default/${fileShareName}'
}
```