# ARM Template deployment fail when deploying azure share - InvalidHeaderValue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage

Im deploying azure storage for a durable function app.
The storage has blob, share, table and file storage.
Ive tried deploying via DEVOPS & manually in the portal via "deploy a custom template".

Most of the other storage types get created, except for fileServices/Shares
Each time i get the same error:

```
{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidHeaderValue",
    "message": "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.\nRequestId:758ffc50-101a-005c-01a6-84927f000000\nTime:2022-06-20T13:05:40.2893940Z"
}
```

}

The ARM code was exported from a successfully created storage account in azure portal.
I changed the API version from 2021-09-01 to 2019-06-01 based on a result of a search of StackOverflow, but this did not help.

Appreciate any advice on what to try next.

code for the fileservice/shares portion of the arm script that keeps failing is below:

```
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'), '/default/', parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'), '04')]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices', parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'), 'default')]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "accessTier": "TransactionOptimized",
      "shareQuota": 5120,
      "enabledProtocols": "SMB"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error **"InvalidHeaderValue"** , try removing properties section from ARM template like below and deploy:

```json
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'), '/default/', parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'), '04')]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices', parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'), 'default')]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_testvalue202206151534_name'))]"
    ]
}
```

- Removing the properties section allows you to continue deployment but it may lead to **runtime unreachable error**.
- Instead of configuring file share separately, let the function app create them by passing the required **app settings**.

Please check this **similar issue** answered by [**Lokanath das**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794222/arm-template-for-fileshare-on-storage-account) that helps you to get rid of the error.

***While performing the deployment, please consider the below points:***

- Make sure to create the storage account first and then create the function app.
- Please check whether you are authorized to access the resource, if not create SAS on file or share level with read permission as mentioned in this [***SO thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045880/cannot-access-windows-azure-file-storage-document/35046177#35046177) by **Gaurav Mantri** like below:

[image]

Please find the below **references** for more information:

[How do I deploy file share within storage account using ARM template - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411072/how-do-i-deploy-file-share-within-storage-account-using-arm-template)

[Azure File Storage URL in browser showing InvalidHeaderValue - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203205/azure-file-storage-url-in-browser-showing-invalidheadervalue)